# So I really need a helping hand with semantic tableaux method

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have this exercise:
Prove that the following formula is tautologie using the semantic tableaux method:​

distribution of ’∨’ over ’⟷’: (p  ∨ (q ⟷ r)) ⟷ ((p ∨ q) ⟷ (p ∨ r));

I tried to do it, but not all the brenches are closed, and I don't know where I did it wrong. I don't need a big salvation, I just need a starting point...

My first thought was ¬((p  ∨ (q ⟷ r)) ⟷ ((p ∨ q) ⟷ (p ∨ r))) =

[(p ∨ (q ⟷ r)) ∧ ¬((p ∨ q) ⟷ (p ∨ r))] ∨ [¬(p ∨ (q ⟷ r)) ∧ ((p ∨ q) ⟷ (p ∨ r))]​

But it has too many branches and many of them are open.

Comment: If you have found at least one branch that is completed and is still open, this is enough to show that the formula is **not** a *tautology*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your attempt, I can't really say where you went wrong...

Anyway, here is a [Tree Proof Generator](https://www.umsu.de/trees/). It's always a good idea to attempt a problem before checking it using the site, and, if you get stuck and view the solution, it's a good idea to attempt the problem again after some time has passed.